# After I ping the ip the NICs will lost their ip

Tags: centos, ip, network-interface, ping

I apologize for I can not copy code from the remote server.

You can see there are three NIC with ip on each one.

[image]

If I ping the `10.10.0.1`, the NIC will lost the ip from them:

[image]

But if I ping `www.google.com` will  not have this issue.